# Jasmine-node - Creating a spy on a constructor called inside other function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine-node, spy

I'm novice in jasmine and I need to write some unit tests for node.js app in this framework.
I have some problems, one of them is this described below:

```
var sampleFunction = function(){
    var loader = new Loader(params);
    // rest of logic here
}
```

I want to write unit test for `sampleFunction`. To do this I need to create spy on `Loader` constructor and check what this constructor gets as params and what kind of object is it returning.

Any ideas how to do that? I tried to create spy on `Loader.prototype.constructor` but it wasn't a solution to this problem.

Comment: Can you paste the entire `sampleFunction` function body?

Comment: How you create the spy depends on where you defined the `Loader` constructor. Please describe where you defined it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so normally in client-side JavaScript you would use the window object like so `jasmine.spyOn(window, 'Loader')`

In node, however, there is no window object and despite claims to the contrary global is not a substitute (unless you are in the REPL which runs in global scope).

```
function MyConstructor () {}
console.log(global.MyConstructor); --> undefined
console.log(this.MyConstructor); --> undefined
```

So, in node you need to attach your constructor to an object. So just do something like this

```
var Helpers = {
   Loader: Loader
};

var constSpy = jasmine.spyOn(Helpers, 'Loader').andCallThrough();

sampleFunction();

expect(constSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

The `andCallThrough` call is only necessary if you want your constructor to do something (often with constructor you do).

This is a little hacky, but it works and seems to be the only way to achieve this through jasmine's implementation within node.

Comment: newer version of jasmine: `.and.callThrough();` instead of `andCallThrough()`